# Безопасность использование exec()

Tags: php, pdf, laravel-8

Использую для парсинга ниже описанную строку.

Сомнения в безопасности, а другого пакета для аналогичной разборки нет, который подходил так же.
Это на уровне роутера можно дополнительно обезопасить доступ, так же использую `laravel passport`.

```
exec("pdftotext -layout \"$input_pdf_file\" - ", $all_lines);
```

Либо как то по другому можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использование `exec` крайне неприемлимо для безопасности приложения. В вашем случае можно использовать библиотеки PHP для парсинга PDF, например, [PDFParser](https://pdfparser.org/)

Comment: PDFParser пробовал ее, она парсит, искревляет данные из pdf. Тоесть,есть слово.
Quantity. pdftotext вернет мне в неизменом виде. PDFParser он может видоизменить Quan tity. Вставить пробел. Хз почему. Но это не приемлимо для дальнейшей моей логики.

Comment: Можно посмотреть на другие библиотеки, благо их немало https://github.com/search?q=php+pdf

Comment: Смотрел и пробовал,не подходил пока не один,либо вообще не парсит, либо коряво,но спасибо) буду дальше рыть.
Главное что-бы библиотека поддерживалась, а то после нового выхода новой версии pdf, может слететь